# R: mpi.spawn.Rslaves() returns timed out

Tags: r

I am running R 3.2.2 on MacOSX. I have installed Rmpi and cannot run correctly Rmpi, right from the beginning. I have looked on several blogs & such, but cannot find a similar question.

mpi.spawn.Rslaves() failed with a timed-out message…

```
> library(Rmpi)
> mpi.spawn.Rslaves()
4 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
[MondoLab-Yoda][[8866,1],0][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:818:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() to 2620:9b::1932:b692 failed: Operation timed out (60)
```

EDIT: Not really solved, but with installing Open MPI, I can now run mpi.spawn.Rslaves

I installed Open MPI with that link as a tutorial: https://wiki.helsinki.fi/display/HUGG/Installing+Open+MPI+on+Mac+OS+X

And then reinstalled RMPI

Test code:

```
> mpi.spawn.Rslaves()
4 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
master (rank 0, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: MondoLab-Yoda 
slave1 (rank 1, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: MondoLab-Yoda 
slave2 (rank 2, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: MondoLab-Yoda 
slave3 (rank 3, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: MondoLab-Yoda 
slave4 (rank 4, comm 1) of size 5 is running on: MondoLab-Yoda
```

and

```
> mpi.remote.exec(sum(1:mpi.comm.rank()))
X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  3  6 10
```

Comment: Please post an answer.